# Background image specified in CSS does not appear in iPad

Tags: css, ipad, mobile-safari, background-image

I have a CSS class where I added a background image like this:

```
.my-class{
   background-image: url(images/my-bg.png);
}
```

this applies fine and works properly in browsers, but when I see it in the iPad, the background image is not visible.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason, the "url(...)" part looks slightly strange - what's that for. i.e, why not just have my-bg.png there?

Comment: Adel - that's the standard way to specify a background image in CSS.

Comment: To which page element have you applied `.my-class`? Do you still see this behaviour if you just use the `background: url(...)` directive? Have you tried setting explicit `no-repeat` directives and so forth? (Might be worth checking in desktop Safari too, if you haven't already).

Answer (score 1):

Without further information (i.e. how you're applying this class, and to which element), I can't help further. I *can* tell you however, that this snippet works just fine on desktop, iPhone and iPad:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .my-class{background-image: url(images/my-bg.png);}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="my-class">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and have managed to get a working solution using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var buttonsFilename = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Buttons.png") %>';

        $('.commands .command').css({
            background: 'url(' + buttonsFilename + ')',
            width: '55px',
            height: '55px',
            display: 'inline-block'
        });
    });
```

I'm using this within an ASP.NET MVC website, hence the `<% %>` tag.

I could only get it to work using the background shortcut css property. I couldn't get any of the following to work ...

- background-image
- backgroundImage
- 'background-image'

... when using the object notation. Unfortunately that wipes out any other background settings you may have. But I got around that by using another piece of jQuery to set my `background-position` property.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and finally after hours of apple bashing and toiling I made a div tag with an ID around my entire site. The iPad loves it :)

Problem solved.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

        #bodybackground {
        background:#999 url('http://mywebsite.com/images/background.jpg')
    }

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="bodybackground">
entire site here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag to your page

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, height = device-height"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was having the same problem, (ie: no background image shown on iPad specifically), the problem was the use of quotes, or lack thereof, when apostrophes were needed...

Problem (no apostrophes)

```
.my-class{background-image: url(images/my-bg.png);}
```

Fix (apostrophes added)

```
.my-class{background-image: url('images/my-bg.png');}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving the .png from photoshop, make sure you save it via 'save for web and devices' and select PNG24.